# Sorting a partially sorted array

Tags: algorithm, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interview Q: sorting an almost sorted array (elements misplaced by no more than k)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726785/interview-q-sorting-an-almost-sorted-array-elements-misplaced-by-no-more-than-k)

I have a partially sorted array with the property that every element is within d units of its properly sorted position.  I am wondering if there is a way to sort this array -- by exploiting this fact -- in less than n log n time.

Comment: Homework?  Interview question?  Or actual application?  (Nice question, by the way.)

Comment: This seems identical to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726785/interview-q-sorting-an-almost-sorted-array-elements-misplaced-by-no-more-than-k

Comment: @Jeff:  Too bad.  I kind of like my answer :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Off the top of my head...

Create a "sliding window" of size 2d.

Start it at [0,2d).  Sort the elements in the window; now elements 0 through d-1 are guaranteed to be correct.

Slide the window forward by d, so now it's [d,3d).  Sort those elements, guaranteeing that elements d through 2d-1 are correct.

Slide it forward another d, so now its [2d,4d).  Sort those.  And so on.

Each sort is O(d log d), and it takes n/d steps to get to the end, so this is O(n/d * d log d) = O(n log d).  If d is constant, that's O(n).

[edit]

You make a good point in a comment; I did not prove that each iteration preserves the property that every element is within d units of its proper position.

So...

Lemma:  If A is an array with the property that every element is within d units of its proper position, and you sort any contiguous subsequence within A to create an array A', then every element in A' is within d units of its proper position.

Proof:  Since this is a lemma about the properties of a sort (not performance), it does not matter what algorithm we use to sort.  So use bubble sort.  Find any two elements in the subsequence that are out of order, and swap them.  There are only three cases: Both elements are before their proper positions in the array; both are after their proper positions in the array; or they are between their proper positions in the array.

For example, suppose A[i] belongs at position i' and A[j] belongs at position j', i < j, but A[i] > A[j].  It follows that i' > j' (because that is where the elements "belong", and A[i] > A[j]).  Case 1: Suppose i' and j' are both greater than i and j; that is, the order goes i < j < j' < i'.  But by hypothesis, i' is only d units from i, so this entire range is only d units wide at most.  So j is also within d units of i' and i is within d units of j', so when we swap A[i] with A[j], both elements are still within d of where they belong.  The analysis for Case 2 and Case 3 are similar.

So each step of a bubble sort -- on any subsequence of A -- will preserve the desired property, from which it follows that the entire bubble sort will preserve the desired property, from which it follows that *any* sort will preserve the desired property.  Q.E.D.

Comment: Thanks.  All of the answers are good but O(n log d) was the bound I was looking for.

Comment: Does this algorithm preserve the property that each element must always be within d units of its properly sorted position?

Comment: @Schemer: That is an excellent question.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Yes; it is possible to sort in O(nd) time. One solution is a simple modification of insertion sort. We process the input array from start to finish; for each element, we look at the last d elements of the output array, and insert the new element in its appropriate position.

There may, of course, be faster algorithms; this particular choice of algorithm was to make it easier to demonstrate asymptotic bound.

Comment: still `O(nd)`, but look between `max 0 (i-d)` ... `min n (i+d)`

Comment: We don't need to look at elements beyond `i`, as we've not inserted any elements beyond there yet. If `i` belongs at `i+d` it'll be put there by later insertions.

Answer (score 4):

Yep. Believe it or not the bubble sort is probably the best for a partially sorted array. It's best case is a fully sorted array in which case its performance is O(n).

Wikipedia on bubble sorts: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Edit: Specifically the "Modified Bubble Sort", with a flag to skip exchanges when it is already in order.

Comment: Insertion sort is probably the way to go. I'm leaving this up for the information. Also consider getting to use a bubble sort and saying it is efficient, which is awesome.

Comment: Is there a place with open source implementation of insertion loss optimized for partially sorted array?

Answer (score 3):

I believe [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) (which Python uses I think?) does exactly this.

Comment: Timsort originates in Python, and is an adaptive sort.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is to use an [adaptive sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_sort). Straight insertion sort is one, timsort is another. These automatically take into account partial sorting.