# Can k-messed-array sort be done in O(1) space using heaps

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, heap

In the familiar problem where every element in an array is at most k positions away from it's correct location, either to the left or to the right, the min-heap implementation is as follows.

> Create a min-heap of size k+1. So, the root of the min heap is the
> smallest element of the sorted array. For the remaining n-(k+1)
> elements, in each iteration, the choice is between a[i] and the
> elements that are already in heap. So insert a[i] in to the heap,
> heapify, and do extract min. This will keep populating the a[i-k]
> elements of the sorted array.
>
> Time  complexity : O(k) + O(n-k).log(k)
>
> Space complexity : O(k)

My question is : Can this be done using O(1) space complexity?

I found an approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726785/sorting-an-almost-sorted-array-elements-misplaced-by-no-more-than-k), but could not sense of it. Could someone elaborate?

> You can do this in-place. Start from the far end, and use a max-heap
> instead of a min-heap. Heapify that final block of 2k elements
> in-place. Store the first extracted element in a variable; subsequent
> elements go in the positions vacated immediately before the final
> block of 2k (which contains the heap structure), similar to regular
> heapsort. When only 1 block remains, heapsort it in place. A final
> O(n) pass is needed to "rotate" the final block back to the initial
> block. The rotation is not trivial but can be done in O(n) and O(1)
> space.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to store the heap in the array, use it to sort the remaining elements of the array, and then sort the heap portion itself.

Here is a variant using a min-heap that might be easier to understand.

1. Heapify the first `k+1` elements of the array, in place.  The minimum element of the heap will be the minimum of the entire array.

   ```
   k+1  | n-(k+1)
   heap | unsorted
   ```
2. Swap the minimum element of the heap with the first element of the unsorted portion and re-heapify.

   ```
   k+1  | 1      | n-(k+2)
   heap | sorted | unsorted
   ```
3. Repeat step 2 until there are no more unprocessed elements.   At this point the heap contains the `k+1` largest elements of the array, and the remaining elements are in sorted order.

   ```
   k+1  | n-(k+1)
   heap | sorted
   ```
4. Sort the heap portion of the array

   ```
   k+1         | n-(k+1)
   sorted heap | sorted
   ```
5. Move the sorted heap to the other end of the array.  The array is now sorted.

   ```
   n-(k+1)| k+1
   sorted | sorted heap
   ```